# get text inside element, if element contains select get selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Post Edited: Using MutationObserver instead of DOMSubtreeModified

I have a div where I am using `.each` to go through every label and get their text, but I'd like to add an additional ifelse statement where if the label includes a select child, add the selected option to the text string

```js
$("#droppable").on('click', '.delete', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove(); // changed - missed "()"
});

var target = document.querySelector('#droppable')
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  var str = "";
 $('#droppable label').each(function(){
 str += $(this).text() + "<br>";
  document.getElementById("inside_drop_zone").innerHTML = str  
 });
})
// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

```css
#droppable {
border: 2px dashed #466683;
padding: 1em;
min-height: 200px;
}

#droppable.ui-droppable-hover {
background: #bad4ed;
}

#droppable select {
margin: 5px;
}

.drop_area {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}

.delete {
  background: none;
  border: 0px;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0px 0 0;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

button:hover {
  color: #CF2323;
}

#inside_drop_zone {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="droppable">
<div class="form-group drop_area">
<label class="control-label" for="one">ONE</label><select id="one-select">
<option value="week1" selected>Week 1</option>
<option value="week2">Week 2</option>
<option value="week3">Week 3</option>
<option value="week4">Week 4</option></select>
<button class="delete">Delete</button>
</div>

<div class="form-group drop_area">
<label class="control-label" for="chg">THREE</label>
<button class="delete">Delete</button>
</div>

<div class="form-group drop_area">
<label class="control-label" for="two">TWO</label><select id="two-select">
<option value="week1" selected>Week 1</option>
<option value="week2">Week 2</option>
<option value="week3">Week 3</option>
<option value="week4">Week 4</option></select>
<button class="delete">Delete</button>
</div>
</div>

<div id="inside_drop_zone"></div>
```

## Desired Output

label OR label : selected option

```
ONE + ":" + week 1 
THREE
TWO + ":" + week 3
```

I'm pretty new to JQuery so thank you for any help/tips!

Comment: Are you looking for only a `:` placement between the label and select box, when the select box is present?

Comment: isnt DOMSubtreeModified deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for lines marked `// changed`

```js
$("#droppable").on('click', '.delete', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove(); // changed - missed "()"
});

$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "#droppable", function() {
  var str = "";
  $('#droppable label').each(function() {
    const txt = $(this).text() // changed
    const val = $(this).parent().find("select").children("option:selected").val() // changed - the main idea is to get parent() of $(this) and then search for <select>
    str += txt + (val ? ":" + val : "") + "<br>"; // changed
  })

  document.getElementById("inside_drop_zone").innerHTML = str
});
```

```css
#droppable {
  border: 2px dashed #466683;
  padding: 1em;
  min-height: 200px;
}

#droppable.ui-droppable-hover {
  background: #bad4ed;
}

#droppable select {
  margin: 5px;
}

.drop_area {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}

.delete {
  background: none;
  border: 0px;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0px 0 0;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

button:hover {
  color: #CF2323;
}

#inside_drop_zone {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="droppable">
  <div class="form-group drop_area">
    <label class="control-label" for="one">ONE</label>
    <select id="one-select">
      <option value="week1" selected>Week 1</option>
      <option value="week2">Week 2</option>
      <option value="week3">Week 3</option>
      <option value="week4">Week 4</option>
    </select>
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group drop_area">
    <label class="control-label" for="chg">THREE</label>
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group drop_area">
    <label class="control-label" for="two">TWO</label>
    <select id="two-select">
      <option value="week1" selected>Week 1</option>
      <option value="week2">Week 2</option>
      <option value="week3">Week 3</option>
      <option value="week4">Week 4</option>
    </select>
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="inside_drop_zone"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is great!!! I slightly edited the post to use `MutationObserver` and hoped that this would be enough to detect select changes inside `#droppable`  but this code only runs when one of the inner divs is deleted, and Ideally I'd like the text to refresh when the user selects a different option. How can I modify your code to include when the option:selected is changed?

Comment: create named function from on('DOMSubtreeModified') callback... let's name it `update_drop_zone()` and add `$('select').on('change', update_drop_zone);`

Comment: Yea... and don't use `MutationObserver`, just remove  on('DOMSubtreeModified') completely and add a call to `update_drop_zone()` inside on('click', '.delete') callback